# Computational cost of calculating the determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix using LU factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, lu-decomposition

How to determine the computational cost associated with calculating determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix using the [LU factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)?

Answer (score 0):

With $M(n)$ the times for mutliplying 2 matrices, the factorization LU requires $O(M(n))$ with $M(n)>n^2$. Classical matrix multiplication complexity is $M(n)=O(n^3)$, some efficient way gives $M(n)=O(2^{2.373})$. To get such complexity for LU decomposition it is  Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm.

Then to get the determinant of the matrix you have to add $2n$ multiplication.

Comment: A = LU
So, det(A) = det(L)*det(u)
On a text book, it says that this is $$ O(n^3) $$
please can you show me how to prove this?

Comment: Given an  decomposition, the determinant is a product of $2n$ numbers, not $n^2$.

Comment: The proof is a bit long to rewrite. You need to count the number of basic operation used in one algorithm, for instance the Crout method. An example with proof is available in this document http://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~halpern/teaching/MACS1_2010/systemes.pdf

Comment: For anyone reading, I believe the Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm is considered galactic, and therefore inefficient/infeasible for implementation on most if not all real datasets.