# Multiplications in determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

Assuming we use Gaussian Elimination/LU decomp, is there a general formula to describe the number of multiplications involved in finding the determinant of an $N \times N$ matrix?

[Find the computational cost associated with calculating determinant of an $n\times n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183603/find-the-computational-cost-associated-with-calculating-determinant-of-an-n-tim)

I stumbled upon what I believed to be the correct answer above, but just wanted to clarify, when it says $M(n) = \mathcal{O}(N^3)$ this means the number of multiplications is $N^3$? Or have I mis-interpreted the answer?

Comment: It says that, at worst, you must do a number of multiplications that is proportional to $N^3$.

Comment: If you don't know what the notation $\mathcal{O}(N^3)$ means, check out this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: The leading term is $n^3/3$.